# how can I get a date from the user in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, datepicker, datetimepicker

I should get a date from the user inside a WP 8.1 app, I need something like the DateTimePicker which I use in Windows Forms or the DatePicker of WPF environment, do you know ho to do this?
I tried to search something similar to DatePicker in windows phone but I can't find anything!

My app should get this date to generate a fiscal code, so I need to get the user's birthday.
Is there any tag to add to my xaml file?
Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You mention that you were searching for something similar to the DatePicker control, yet the framework has this control built in.  Did this control not do what you expected, or were you not able to add the control to your page?  A bit more context would help us to provide a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem!

```
<DatePicker x:Name=birthdayDatePicker Header="Birthday Date"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is what kind of WP 8.1 app you're developing? *Windows Runtime* or *Silverlight*? If the first one, then you can just use `DatePicker` control, because it's built in.

But, if your app uses *Silverlight*, then you have to import *Windows Phone Toolkit* first. You can do it easily: right-click on your project name in *Solution Explorer*, then choose *Manage NuGet Packages...*. Type `wptoolkit` in a search box and you will find *Windows Phone Toolkit*. Just install it. Now, go to you XAML code and add `toolkit` namespace:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Now you can add `DatePicker` to your layout:

```
<toolkit:DatePicker Header="Birthday date"/>
```